# div disappears when page refreshed

Tags: javascript, html

Can't figure out why the below piece of code makes the textfield disappear upon page refresh (when 'No' radio button selected).
Also, after the page is refreshed the default radio button doesn't get selected.

Forcing refresh, fixes the problem, though.

Any ideas?

```
<html>
<body>
<div class="editfield">
        <div id="field_1">
            <label>
                <input type="radio" checked="checked" name="radio-1" id="radio-1_id" value="Yes" onclick="document.getElementById('divUrl').style.display='none'">Yes
        </label>
            <label>
                <input type="radio" name="radio-1" id="radio-2_id" value="No" onclick="document.getElementById('divUrl').style.display='block'">No
        </label>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="editfield" id="divUrl" style="display:none">
    <label>Website URL</label>
    <input type="text" name="X" id="X_id" value="" />
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Because of `style="display:none"` given in the `.editfield`?

Comment: Are you in Firefox by any chance? Some versions of Firefox remember DOM states on refresh, and only reset on hard refreshes.

Comment: the onclick action will only work when you click on the element (these states aren't remembered after refresh), and because the div is hidden by default, on refresh the div will remain hidden.

Comment: while on refresh the div should remain hidden, the radio button selected should be the "Yes" one. i did check it out and in Mozilla and under the Trident engine (IE 7-11) the "No" remains selected, while the div is hidden. On Chrome, Opera and Safari everything works as expected (latest versions used, Trident engine tried in Maxthon)

Comment: Thanks all for replies. Thanks for testing in elsewhere. I am F28 on Fedora 20 at the moment.

What would be the way around to have 'Yes' selected after refresh, and the div hidden?

Comment: add the `onLoad="document.getElementById('radio-2_id').checked=false; document.getElementById('radio-1_id').checked=true;"` on the body or put the js in the onload if you have it in a js file ... can't figure out why this is happening ... also, you have an extra `</div>` in the middle, but i tested without that and it didn't impact the results.

Comment: Well spotted. Corrected in the post. I will test your suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">
<body onLoad="document.getElementById('radio-2_id').checked=false; document.getElementById('radio-1_id').checked=true;">
<div class="editfield">
        <div id="field_1">
            <input type="radio" checked="checked" name="radio-1" id="radio-1_id" value="Yes" onclick="document.getElementById('divUrl').style.display='none'">
            <label for='radio-1_id'>
                Yes
        </label>
            <input type="radio" name="radio-1" id="radio-2_id" value="No" onclick="document.getElementById('divUrl').style.display='block'">
            <label for='radio-2_id'>
                No
        </label>
        </div>
</div>
<div class="editfield" id="divUrl" style="display:none">
    <label>Website URL</label>
    <input type="text" name="X" id="X_id" value="" />
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

just a short recap: 

1. on page refresh the div should disappear (all css and js and html that was dynamically set / added is removed) and the selected radio button should be the first (Yes)

2. tested this on all major browser and it works 

3. still can't figure out why it wasn't working on Mozilla and IE without the JS refresh

I moved the radio buttons out of the labels to see if that impacted the refresh in any way and it didn't. Also, I removed an extra `</div>` that was in the original code.

Comment: That is working well now on latest Firefox, Chrome and Safari. Bravo.

Answer (score 0):

The page refresh will initiate the page in its' original state. So the

```
style="display:none"
```

will be reactivated on the div and will be hidden and the "Yes" button will also be reenabled

Comment: That does not happen in my case (F28). 'Yes' does not get re-enabled upon refresh, which is something I would love to have.
See the comments above for some explanations.

Answer (score 0):

what i did have a textarea insert number first ,0 make it readonly
then it will not disappear on refresh,to insert document.getElementById("demo").readOnly=false,and true to enable readonly